# Add class after a user scrolls up/down

Tags: jquery

My website currently has a lot of local scrolling links. I would like to be able to add a class to the div .show__wrapper after a user scrolls. I currently have the code below, but this triggers the addClass when the local scroll is triggered too.

The class should only be added when the local scroll is finished and the users scrolls up or down after that. Can this be done at all?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.show__wrapper').addClass('test');
  }, 500)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whats the value of the scroll for example:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 500) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".show__wrapper").addClass("test");
    }
    }
}); 
);
```

Comment: This won't work for my website, unfortunately. The website is a long list of events, to which of all of these events you can locally scroll. So the offset of >= is always triggered when scrolling to events that are near the bottom of the page.

Comment: @imrafaelhi well can you explain more briefly whats your situation, as i can see my answer is correct for your question

Comment: Perhaps it helps if you "see" it in action. The frontpage is https://letsmosh.nl/, which is a long list of events. The single post of each event redirectsback  to frontpage and scrolls you to the event you are trying to view (letsmosh.nl/4247/ -> this scrolls you to the correspondending event).

The "active" event you are scrolled towards, gets added the class "current__show" (this is done by fetching the ID which matches the # in the URL).

The idea is the remove the class "current__show" after scrolling up or down, AFTER you have been scrolled towards the event.